# Can the word attendance be used to describe the state or action of being an attendant?

Tags: single-word-requests

According to Wiktionary, an attendant is "One who attends; one who works with or watches over something". When one is an attendant, is it grammatically correct to describe the state of being an attendant by saying "I am doing attendance"?

Comment: Use the idiomatic phrase "in attendance," instead:  "Accompanying a member of royalty or other important person as an assistant or servant." https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/attendance

Comment: Also, a patient's family member present to take care of them in a hospital is usually referred to as a patient's "attendant."

Comment: @Kris "I am attending to" is also common, although I will admit that it implies active engagement whereas "being in attendace" includes the possibility of standing and waiting to be needed.

Comment: ... "_doing_ attendance" sounds like something a teacher does before starting class.

Comment: @BoldBen "I am attending on" might be more idiomatic, instead.

Comment: @Cascabel Native speakers do not usually say "doing attendance." Also, it's not clear if it's "taking" or "giving" attendance in this case; it could be used both ways.

Comment: @kris Perhaps that's one of those difference between US and British English. I don't think I've ever heard a Brit say that they were "attending on" someone.

Comment: @BoldBen Actually, it's more BrE than AmE.

Answer (score 1):

"I am doing attendance" is likely to be understood as the speaker saying they are noting who showed up, as in a teacher "taking attendance".

Someone watching over a place, such as a parking lot, might say "I am attending the lot", though in America that might sound odd. A more likely phrase would be "I am the attendant" with the activity described in more precise terms, such as "I take the money for parking, and watch over the cars."

If one is an attendant to a royal personage, they might say, for example, "I am attending the Duchess."

In the situation where a particular task is the subject, one might say "I am attending to it." E.g. "I am attending to the garbage" or "I am attending to the email." This has a somewhat lofty feel to American ears, but isn't uncommon.